# Kivy / KivyMD: Dynamically generated buttons with own actions

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Could anybody try to help me with this issue?
I have some trouble with creating of dynamic buttons and bind the adequate output response to them.

Please see this example bellow ⬇:

##### Source code

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Demo(App):
    buttons = {"1": {"Name": "Button 1", "Action": "Message 1"},
               "2": {"Name": "Button 2", "Action": "Message 2"},
               "3": {"Name": "Button 3", "Action": "Message 3"}}

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=10, spacing=10)
        for key, value in self.buttons.items():
            layout.add_widget(Button(text=value["Name"], on_press=lambda x: print(value["Action"])))

        return layout

Demo().run()
```

##### Outputs

###### Click "**Button 1**":

```
Message 3
```

###### Click "**Button 2**":

```
Message 3
```

###### Click "**Button 3**":

```
Message 3
```

#### Question

As You can see, I've created a dictionary with "subsection" for every button ('Name' and some 'Action').
I would say that this is a nice simple idea.

The trouble is, that even when the names of the buttons are identified well, the outputs are the same for each button...

Does anybody know how is possible to do it correctly and bind the right action to the buttons?

Thank You a lot.

Comment: Did you try using `partial` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if is this the right hint for solution of that issue...
... and honestly, not even sure how to use it in this situation... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace the line :

```py
layout.add_widget(Button(text=value["Name"], on_press=lambda x: print(value["Action"])))
```

with the following (using [`partial`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=partial#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind)).

```py
layout.add_widget(Button(text=value["Name"], on_press=partial(print, value["Action"])))
```

To have a sense of what's actually happening (and for advanced usage) you can try the following,

```py
    def build(self):
        ...
        for key, value in self.buttons.items():
            # Create an instance.
            btn = Button(text=value["Name"])
            # Bind to some callback and pass
            # whatever you want using partial.
            btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.callback_method, value["Action"]))
            # Now add it.
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        return layout

    def callback_method(self, val, btn):
        # Note the order of the args that have been passed.
        print(val)
```

Comment: I see... 
GREAT! ApuCoder, Thank You sooo much. It works. 